# Reiterating the piecewise-and-uniform-limit operation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request

Probably a hopeless question, but:

Let $C$ be the class of constant functions $f$: $[a, b]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{P}(C))$ denote the class of uniform limits of piecewise constant functions, i.e. the regulated functions. Then let $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{P}(C))))$ denote the class of uniform limits of piecewise regulated functions, and so on.

How far (in the realm of bounded functions on a compact interval) can we get by recursively applying the operations $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{U}$? What if we start with the class of continuous functions instead?

(This question is motivated by the fact that we can extend the notion of integral to $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{P}(C))$ in the obvious way, once it is defined for the class $C$)

$\textbf{Formally:}$ $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is the collection of $\sum\limits_{i}f_i 1_{I_i}$, where $f_i\in X$, $\{I_i\}$ is finite partition of $[a, b]$ into non-degenerate intervals and $1_{(.)}$ are characteristic/indicator functions. $\mathcal{U}(X)$ is the collection of limits of the uniformly convergent sequences of elements in $X$.

Comment: You need to tell us what the operators $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal U$ are. I imagine $\mathcal U(S)$ is the set of all uniform limits of sequences in $S$. And I imagine that $\mathcal P(C)$ is the class of piecewise-constatnt functions, also known as step functions, but that really doesn't tell me what $\mathcal P$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't get any farther than regulated functions. In fact, assuming that you mean $\mathcal{P}$ to be an operator that takes a class of functions to functions that are piecewise the restriction of elements of that class.

$$\mathcal{P(U(P(}C))) = \mathcal{U(P(}C))$$

That is, a piecewise regulated function is regulated.This is fairly immediate if you take the equivalent definition of regulated functions as those for which all one-sided limits exist.

If you want to prove this without invoking that equivalency, suppose $F$ is piecewise regulated, so that there is some partition $a = a_0 < a_1 < ... < a_n =b$ of a $[a,b]$ and regulated functions $F_i: [a_{i - 1},a_i] \to X$. Then there are sequences $f_{(i,j)} \to F_i$ uniformly as $j \to \infty$ of piecewise constant functions. But then we can also define $g_j(x) = f_{(i,j)}(x)$ for $x \in [a_{i-1},a_i]$(playing a little fast and loose with possible boundary conditions) and it is fairly quick to check that $g_j \to F$ uniformly and that the $g_j$ are piecewise constant.  Thus $F$ is regulated.

Comment: Right. All the time I had in mind the counterexample $f=0$ on $[-1, 0]$ and $=\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0, 1]$ of a non-regulated piecewise regulated function, but of course they must be bounded!

Comment: Is this equally easy when $C$ are the continuous functions? I.e. is the class of uniform limits of piecewise continuous functions (whatever that might be) closed under forming piecewise functions?

Comment: One should be careful about what one means by piecewise continuous, but regardless of convention the above argument should carry through. The essential observation is just that a piecewise uniform limit of piecewise ____ functions can be rewritten as the uniform limit of a piecewise-piecewise-____ function as finitely many convergent sequences converge uniformly, and of course piecewise-piecewise____ is just piecewise-____

Comment: My remark about convention is the following: let $S(I)$ be some class of functions on intervals, closed under restrictions. One can conceive of a number of definitions of "piecewise $S$". That is, $f \in \mathcal{P}(S([a,b]))$ could meanthat given some partition $f = f_i$ on each subinterval $I_i$ of the partition where (i) $f_i \in S([a,b])$ (this is a bit of a wierd choice) (ii) $f_i \in S(\bar{I_i})$ (so we close the interval $I_i$), and (iii) $f_i \in S(I_i)$. The distinction is that not every continuous function on $[0,1)$ is the restriction of one on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Sure. Are you perhaps aware of a characterization of uniform limits of piecewise continuous functions (any convention) in the flavour of the one-sided limits characterization for regulated functions?

Comment: Do we really get more than the regulated ones?

Comment: If you use the conventions (i) or (ii), which are equivalent if $S$ denotes continuous functions (I can't really think of a useful $S$ condition where (i),(ii) aren't equivalent), you again get regulated functions. This is simply because constant $\subset$ continuous $\subset$ regulated so if you apply $\mathcal{U(P(}\cdot))$ to all three classes you see that you must end with equality. If you choose convention (iii) then it will be wierder, as a piecewise continuous function under that convention may not be regulated.